# SSRS Dataset for KPI, multiple calculations

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2017

I am trying to setup a KPI that indicates the total of something in the data set used for the trend data.

In this case the KPI can't seem to display a Sum'ed or Max'ed value, you have to do that action in the dataset query. I already have the data that reports the totals for each day to populate the bargraph graphic on the KPI, and it seems very wasteful to be required to create the exact same dataset again, only changing `SELECT DayTotal FROM Table` to `SELECT SUM(DayTotal) FROM Table`

Is there a way to have this calculated dataset be based off of the initial dataset so that I don't have two effectively identical datasets to maintain?

Comment: yes you can.. but it depends on how you group your data and where you place the sum and max of your data. Need to share an image of your design view of your report

Comment: I think you can add a calculated field  to your dataset and it can return sum or max value in one field.